# Error when passing string to scp in for loop

Tags: linux, debian, bash, scp

I'm grabbing file list from server via find via ssh

```
for f in `ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} -l ${SSH_USER} ${SSH_HOST} -t "find ${DIR_REMOTE} -type f | grep jpg" 2> /dev/null`
```

When I echo the list in the body of for loop (`echo ${f}`) everything is ok:

```
/a3/obieg/skan001/skan001.jpg
/a3/obieg/skan001/skan000.jpg
/a3/obieg/skan001/skan003.jpg
/a3/obieg/skan001/skan002.jpg
/a3/obieg/skan.jpg
```

But when I'm trying to copy it via scp (in the same loop) (`scp -p -P ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}:"${f}" "${DIR_SUB}${2}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N.jpg)"`), the result is:

```
: No such file or directory001.jpg
: No such file or directory000.jpg
: No such file or directory003.jpg
: No such file or directory002.jpg
: No such file or directory
```

I can't understand what's happening here…

whole script:

```
SSH_USER=username
SSH_HOST=${1}
SSH_PORT=22

DIR_REMOTE="/a3/obieg/"
DIR_LOCAL="/b2/skany_temp_test/ot/"
DIR_SUB="${DIR_LOCAL}${2}/"

# foldery
mkdir "${DIR_LOCAL}" 2> /dev/null
mkdir "${DIR_SUB}" 2> /dev/null

# sync
for f in `ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} -l ${SSH_USER} ${SSH_HOST} -t "find ${DIR_REMOTE} -type f | grep jpg" 2> /dev/null`
do
#   echo ${f}
    scp -p -P ${SSH_PORT} ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}:"$f" "${DIR_SUB}${2}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%N.jpg)"
    # ssh -p ${SSH_PORT} -l ${SSH_USER} ${SSH_HOST} -t "rm ${f}"
done
```

Comment: show your whole script if you need help

Comment: whole script: http://pastebin.com/eCrhtS7M

Comment: show your code in your questions, don't use external source

Comment: ok, code is now in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I think i have found the solution.

I've replaced the `scp` with `rsync` and it shown me the full path (which, in this case, was ended by ascii-sequence `#\015`).

It looks like  `scp` was looking for a file `/some-path/some-file.jpg\r`, because for loop divided the lines by `\n`

`ssh -t` allocates a pseudo-terminal, which returns windows-like line endings (`\r\n`), [just like the `screen` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76201/line-endings-when-using-gnu-screen).

I've piped every ssh answer via `dos2unix`, and now it works.

Comment: Hi mat, welcome to SF! I think your answer works but not for the reason you state. I'd be interested to see if the answer I posted also works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do

```
${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}:"$(echo $f)"
```

in your SCP command. I'd expect that this should work fine:

```
${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}:"${f}"
```

EDIT: re-reading your answer below, if you were going to `echo` in the copy command you'd need to do `echo -n` to disable printing a newline at the end.

Comment: That `$(echo $f)` was only for testing purposes, originally it was just `$f`. I've edited the code in question.

Comment: Aha! Fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

- you can write **find** part more efficient (make sense when you have large amount of files)
  `find ${DIR_REMOTE} -type f -name "*.jpg" 2>/dev/null`
- also you can **strip** carriage return chars (\r) with sed:
  `find ${DIR_REMOTE} -type f -name "*.jpg" 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\r//g'`